# compare various database like oracle,mysql,mssql,db3, etc..?

Tags: database

Most of people they are using various data base system,

which is best according yours?

and tell me why ?  and also tell me feature .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask : "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.", "avoid asking subjective questions where ... every answer is equally valid: - “What’s your favorite _?”"

Answer (score 0):

There is no "best". Each one has many quirks and many exciting features:

Relational:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems

http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/MySQL_vs_PostgreSQL

NoSQL:

http://nosql-database.org/